# How do I find out the JRE network settings programmatically?

Tags: c#, java, windows

I'm writing a tool to check preconditions for an application. One prerequisite are specific JRE proxy settings. But I couldn't figure out, where JRE stores those informations on a windows machine (this should work on XP, Vista 32/64Bit and win7 32/64Bit) after setting them in the java control panel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

(User Application Data Folder)\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

If any proxy settings are configured they can be found in this file.
Sometimes a systemwide configuration exists then its found in c:\windows\sun...

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

check if the system property

```
http.proxyHost
http.proxyPort
```

are set. There are some more properties like usernames and different ones for socks proxies but basically i would do it like this.

Description of some of the proxy properties
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Thanks, that would help, but the tool I'm writing is in C#. I probably should have mentioned that ;)

Comment: i wondered about the C# tag in the post ;-) so i think jonas s post is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Just print all the system properties once and see if they contain the ones you're looking for.

```
System.getProperties()
```

in Java